# Header, content and footer inside a div with position absolute

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a div element with absolute position. The position value is important and cannot be changed. How can I set a header, content and a footer inside that div?

The height of the header and footer are fixed and the content should take all the space that is left. It's also important that header always stays on top and footer on bottom.

The parent element should also be resizable with south resizable handle and the content should alter its height according to the height of the parent element.

```
.content {
    height: ?; /* What should this be?? */
}
```

An example of the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/7gPzF/26/

Comment: Would you be kind enough to offer some votes and comments to those that helped you so others who view this page can see what was helpful and what was not?

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! None of the solutions below gave me a direct fix. The first answer gave me the basic structure to solve this, thanks Obsidion. Here's the final version which I ended up using on my site: http://jsfiddle.net/7gPzF/95/

Comment: @Q D Your welcome. Does that mean my answer can be marked as correct?

Comment: Yeah, sure. It's close enough to what I was looking for. I'm new here and not yet familiar with all the procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## DEMO

One way to do this is to make middle content position absolute and move the header and footer inside it. Then use padding to offset the head and foot space.

**HTML**

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  bottom: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  /* What should this be?? */
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  /* padding height of header/footer */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap" id="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    text text text text
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what will happen if i enter more text in the content area?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I have updated the demo to compensate. I changed content to position relative and removed fixed height of wrapper. If the user wants fixed height in wrapper then overflow hidden should be set as expanding is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand completely what you meant I guess,
But take a look at this code, is this what you ment?

Made the footer

```
position absolute, bottom:0px; right:0px; left:0px;
```

and gave the content

```
height:auto;
```

**UPDATE:** I've seen the solution above me won't solve the problem, if you place lots of text in the content it will go underneath it.

**UPDATED LINK:** http://jsfiddle.net/7gPzF/42/

I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

with jQuery you can calculate the height of the left space for .content

```
var heightt = $("#header").outerHeight() + $("#footer").outerHeight();
    $("#content").css("height", "calc(100% - "+ heightt + "px" ).css("position", "absolute");
```

Here is working: http://jsfiddle.net/yX4Py/

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know height of header and footer you can use Javascript solution.

Like this:

```
$('#wrap .content').height($('#wrap').height() - $('#wrap .footer').outerHeight() - $('#wrap .header').outerHeight());
```

Your example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7gPzF/41/